# Rate of convergence in Newton's method in Numerical Optimization

Tags: optimization, rate-of-convergence

i'm reading [Numerical Optimization](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf).

In page 45, Newton's method: "Since $\nabla ^{2} f\left( x^{*}\right)$ is nonsingular, there is a radius r > 0 such that $\Vert \nabla ^{2} f^{-1}_{k}\Vert \leqslant 2\Vert \nabla ^{2} f\left( x^{*}\right)^{-1}\Vert$ for all $x_{k}$ with $\Vert x_{k} -x^{*}\Vert \leqslant r$".
I don't understand why, can anyone please explain for me.(Sorry for not typing all the criteria because it is too long and relevant to other section )

Comment: Your link is broken.  However, it appears that you're referring to the proof of theorem 3.5 in Nocedal and Wright's Numerical Optimization, 2nd ed.  The theorem has the hyothesis that $\nabla^{2} f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous in a neighborhood of $x^{*}$.  You need that hypothesis here.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you for the reply. From your hint, i see that r here imply the use of Lipschitz condition, which is $\Vert \nabla ^{2} f( x_{k}) -\nabla ^{2} f( x_{0})\Vert \leqslant \Vert x_{k} -x^{*}\Vert $. But i still don't see how can i apply it

Comment: No, Lipschitz continuit of the Hessian means that there is a constant $L$ such that $\| \nabla^{2}f(x_{k})-\nabla^{2}(f(x^{*}) \| \leq L \| x_{k}-x^{*} \|$.  Furthermore, when $x^{*}$ is sufficently far from any point of singularity, the inverse of the Hessian is also continuous.

Comment: Sorry i mistyped the Lipschitz condition, from my poor algebra skills, i was trying to do something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/GplHDU3) (i don't know why i can't use mathjax here). I still not know how can i derive the coefficient 2. Or maybe me approach is wrong.

Comment: this question is actually duplicated, anyone run into this question should take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846580/properties-of-norms-of-inverse-hessians-near-a-solution)